# Discord Bot | discord.js | TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a Discord bot, and I am using CodeLyon's [Permissions V2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xpdIzcK3v3E&list=PLbbLC0BLaGjpyzN1rg-gK4dUqbn8eJQq4&index=21) video as a reference.

The error is in my message.js file which has the following contents:

```js
require('dotenv').config();
//create cooldowns map
const cooldowns = new Map();
module.exports = (Discord, client, message) => {
    const prefix = process.env.PREFIX;
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/)
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find(a => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    const validPermissions = [
        "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
        "KICK_MEMBERS",
        "BAN_MEMBERS",
        "ADMINISTRATOR",
        "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
        "MANAGE_GUILD",
        "ADD_REACTIONS",
        "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
        "PRIORITY_SPEAKER",
        "STREAM",
        "VIEW_CHANNEL",
        "SEND_MESSAGES",
        "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES",
        "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
        "EMBED_LINKS",
        "ATTACH_FILES",
        "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
        "MENTION_EVERYONE",
        "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS",
        "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS",
        "CONNECT",
        "SPEAK",
        "MUTE_MEMBERS",
        "DEAFEN_MEMBERS",
        "MOVE_MEMBERS",
        "USE_VAD",
        "CHANGE_NICKNAME",
        "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
        "MANAGE_ROLES",
        "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS",
        "MANAGE_EMOJIS",
      ]
    
    
    if(command.permissions.length){
        let invalidPerms = []
        for(const perm of command.permissions){
            if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
                return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
            }
            if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
            invalidPerms.push(perm);
            }
        }
        if (invalidPerms.length){
          return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
        }
    }

    //If cooldowns map doesn't have a command.name key then create one.
    try{
        if(!cooldowns.has(command.name)){
            cooldowns.set(command.name, new Discord.Collection());
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return message.reply("my commands are limited. I can\'t find that command!");
    }

    const current_time = Date.now();
    const time_stamps = cooldowns.get(command.name);
    const cooldown_amount = (command.cooldown) * 1000;

    //If time_stamps has a key with the author's id then check the expiration time to send a message to a user.
    if(time_stamps.has(message.author.id)){
        const expiration_time = time_stamps.get(message.author.id) + cooldown_amount;

        if(current_time < expiration_time){
            const time_left = (expiration_time - current_time) / 1000;

            return message.reply(`Please wait ${time_left.toFixed(1)} more seconds before using ${command.name}`);
        }
    }

    //If the author's id is not in time_stamps then add them with the current time.
    time_stamps.set(message.author.id, current_time);
    //Delete the user's id once the cooldown is over.
    setTimeout(() => time_stamps.delete(message.author.id), cooldown_amount);

    try{
        command.execute(client, message, cmd, args, Discord);
    } catch (err){
        message.reply("There was an error trying to execute this command!");
        console.log(err);
    }

}
```

I have added some "permission code" in my message.js, but it says that the length of `command.permissions.length` is not valid.

Do I need to change or update any packages? Please tell me in the comments if I need to clarify anything.

**EDIT:** Solved! In my `module.exports` object, I forgot to put the permissions value. @Ivar said something about this, but I was inexperienced at the time and didn't quite know what he was talking about.

Comment: What does it mean that _the length of `command.permissions.length` is not valid_. Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: "_Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_" means that it cannot read `length` from something that is `undefined`. So if this error is thrown on `command.permissions.length`, then `command.permissions` has the value `undefined`. In other words `command` exists, but doesn't have a `permissions` property.

Comment: Well, in the video it says that it works, but how do I get around this?

Comment: I can't tell you much more than I did in my last comment I'm afraid. I'm not very familiar with Discord.js. I've looked at the documentation but can't find any `commands` in there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! In my module.exports object, I forgot to put the permissions value. @Ivar said something about this, but I was inexperienced at the time and didn't quite know what he was talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if anyone answered yet but you just need
if(!command) return; on line 12 and youll be good.
its giving you the error if someone is giving a command you havent defined

Comment: It's fine, I solved it. I realized that in my command files, I didn't put the permissions value, so that's why the permissions value was undefined. Thanks, though!