# Error while trying to make a discord bot using java script

Tags: discord.js, bots

I'm trying to implement a permission handler that I saw in a video, on my discord.js bot, but this error always happens (Cannot read property 'length' of undefined) and the bot stops. Can someone help me solve this problem?

````
    const cmd = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(cmd) || client.commands.find((a) => a.aliases && a.aliases.includes(cmd));

    const validPermissions = [
      "CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE",
      "KICK_MEMBERS",
      "BAN_MEMBERS",
      "ADMINISTRATOR",
      "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
      "MANAGE_GUILD",
      "ADD_REACTIONS",
      "VIEW_AUDIT_LOG",
      "PRIORITY_SPEAKER",
      "STREAM",
      "VIEW_CHANNEL",
      "SEND_MESSAGES",
      "SEND_TTS_MESSAGES",
      "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
      "EMBED_LINKS",
      "ATTACH_FILES",
      "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
      "MENTION_EVERYONE",
      "USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS",
      "VIEW_GUILD_INSIGHTS",
      "CONNECT",
      "SPEAK",
      "MUTE_MEMBERS",
      "DEAFEN_MEMBERS",
      "MOVE_MEMBERS",
      "USE_VAD",
      "CHANGE_NICKNAME",
      "MANAGE_NICKNAMES",
      "MANAGE_ROLES",
      "MANAGE_WEBHOOKS",
      "MANAGE_EMOJIS",
    ]
  
    if(command.permission.length){
      let invalidPerms = []
      for(const perm of command.permissions){
        if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
          return message.channel.send(`Invalid Permissions \`${perm}\``);
        }
        if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
          invalidPerms.push(perm);
        }
      }
      if (invalidPerms.length){
        return message.channel.send(`Missing Permissions: \`${invalidPerms}\``);
      }
    }```
````

Answer (score 1):

"Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" means that Node JS can't find the object that you're trying to get the `length` property on (also known as undefined).  In this case, it means that the `permission` property on your `command` object does not exist.

```
command 
     permission <- but this object doesn't exist! Node is now "lost", hence the error.
          length <- Node trying to find this property on above object
```

Looking in the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client), I could not find anything referring to a `command` object.

Perhaps in another section of your code you need to define this `permission` property on your `command` object.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66329415/discord-bot-discord-js-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined) seems to have the issue as you. As per the accepted answer, did you export the `permissions` value through `module.export`?